# Django-filter filter by related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have two tables.

```
class Writer(models.Model)
    name = model.CharField()
    ...

class Article(models.Model)
    name = model.CharField()
    writer = model.ForeignKey('Writer', related_name="relationship") 
    ...
```

I wanted to build some API endpoints getting the writer list, but this should be filterable by Article id.
I am using django-filter. So:

```
class WriterViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   filter_backend = [filters.djangoFilterBackend],
   filter_class = WriterFilter


class WriteFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
....
```

So my concern is, how can I define WriteFilter to filter Writer by the article?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class WriteFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    article = django_filters.CharFilter(name='relationship__name', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = WriterFilter
        fields = ['article']
```

Your url will be like this,
`/api/wtiter/list/?article=somearticlename`

---

#### UPDATE-1

since **`django-filter 2.0`**, the **`name`** argument changed to **`field_name`**.
 Hence the filter class will be,

```
class WriteFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    article = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='relationship__name', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = WriterFilter
        fields = ['article']
```

Comment: Since release 2.0 the `name` argument is not supported anymore. Use `field_name` instead.

Comment: @Jesse Thanx for the update. I've updated the answer

Comment: It will be extremely tedious when you have lots of fields and relations. See my answer for a better solution

Answer (score 5):

JPG answer is right, but if you got lots of fields and relations it will be tedious work. But you can actually declare relations in `field` meta:

```
class ArticleFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['article', 'writer__name']
```

Or with lookup expressions:

```
class ArticleFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = {
            'article': ('exact', ),
            'relationship__name': ('exact', 'contains')
            }
```

And even more optimization:

```
def prefix_dict_keys(prefix: str, d: dict):
    return {prefix + k: v for k, v in d.items()}

class ArticleFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = {
            'article': ('exact', ),
            ...
            **prefix_dict_keys('writer__'
                {
                   'name': ('exact', 'contains')),
                   ...
                }),
            ...
            }
```

Comment: This answer must be marked as best answer. 
What for to make custom filter, if we can use built-in functionality.

Comment: you wrote the article filter, not the writer filter though

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this. My class custom your filter with new param. Your api must have extra param . In this case is ?article_name='example'

```
class WriteFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = WriterFilter
        fields = ['article_name']
    article_name = ArticleFilter(name="article_name")

class ArticleFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        return qs.article_set.filter(name=value)
```

If you run queryset, it will get all Writer with article name is 'example'.

Hoop this help