# How to serialize a custom data set of two models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a super important query: I want to serialize a set of data, or rather a model that has foreign keys of another model, so that through the foreign key I want to show the field of the other table, like the name:

Model Equipos

```
    id_equipo=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    vendedor=models.CharField(max_length=10,default='S/A',blank=True)
    ip_gestion=models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='Ipv4',default='0.0.0.0')
    tipo=models.CharField(max_length=8,default='S/A',blank=True)
    localidad=models.CharField(max_length=5,default='S/A',blank=True)
    categoria=models.CharField(max_length=10,default='S/A',blank=True)
    ultima_actualizacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Equipos'
```

Model Interfaces

```
class Interfaces(models.Model):

    id_interface=models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_EquipoOrigen=models.ForeignKey(Equipos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='equipo_origen')

id_PuertoOrigen=models.ForeignKey(Puertos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='puerto_origen',null=True,blank=True)
    estatus=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    etiqueta_prtg=models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True)
    grupo=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    if_index=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    bw=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    bw_al=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    id_prtg=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    ospf=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    id_EquipoDestino=models.ForeignKey(Equipos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='equipo_destino')
    id_PuertoDestino=models.ForeignKey(Puertos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='puerto_destino')
    ultima_actualizacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So I want to create a serializer where, through the Id_EquipoOrigen (which refers to the Equipos model) of the interfaces model, it is able to be able to present in a json the fields nombre, localidad, categoria of the Equipos model.

I already have my Serialized Equipment and Interfaces models

```
class EquipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Equipos
        fields=('id_equipo','nombre','vendedor','ip_gestion','tipo','localidad','categoria','ultima_actualizacion')

# Serializando los Datos del Modelo Equipo_Interface(Registros)
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','ultima_actualizacion') 

class EquiposViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Equipos.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EquipoSerializer

class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class=PostPageNumberPagination
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by nesting the `EquipoSerializer` (or creating a shorter version of it with only the fields you want to show), something like this:

```
class EquipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Equipos
        fields=('id_equipo','nombre','vendedor','ip_gestion','tipo','localidad','categoria','ultima_actualizacion')

class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id_EquipoOrigen = EquipoSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','ultima_actualizacion')
```

and for the shorter version of it you could do:

```
class NestedEquipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Equpos
        fields = ('id_equipo', 'nombre', 'localidad', 'categoria',)
```

the other approach is to get the fields directly in the `InterfaceSerializer`:

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        nombre_equipo = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre')
        categoria_equipo = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.categoria')
        localidad_equipo = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.localidad')

        class Meta:
            model=Interfaces
            fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','ultima_actualizacion', 
                    'nombre_equipo', 'categoria_equipo', 'localidad_equipo')
```

Comment: And as I would do if I want to show within the interface model, that according to the id value that has the field id_EquipoDestino, show me the nombre, categoria and localidad  of that team, which is already in the Equipo Model.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - by nesting you'll have the exact serialized object you want inside the `Interface` serialized object. If instead of serializing a nested object you want the fields directly, you can declare new fields on the `InterfaceSerializer` like this: `nombre_equipo = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre')`, by specifying the `source` and then you'd need to add `nombre_equipo`  to your `fields`.

Comment: Just what I needed, direct fields, thank you very much for your help friend

Comment: I'll edit the answer with a more detailed explanation then, cheers! :)

Comment: TypeError: 'Teams' object does not support item assignment I have this error when trying to make a post (create) because it tells me that it is necessary to place the fields of name, location, category of the Model Equipo, as I would do to cancel this since I only would like to create / edit with id..

Comment: You can define the fields to be `read_only=True`, e.g, `nombre_equipo = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigin.nombre', read_only=True)`

Comment: Hello friend, how do you happen to know how to solve this problem that happens to me when doing a filter with those specific fields that I am bringing through the foreign key? I leave the code in pastebin. The problem in question is: TypeError: 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: EquipoOrigen. https://pastebin.com/rmSNTNL2

Comment: by using the `FilterSet` you'll need to [customize it a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468071/django-filter-filter-by-related-fields), because you'd be filtering by a related field

Comment: Thanks I help a lot

Comment: Friend would know how I could generate an EXCEL with this serialized and customized model to be consumed from a frontend (Angular)?.Which I have no idea