# combining multiple queryset based on conditions Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I am using Djangofilterbackend and DjangoRestFramework.

I am using `query parameters` to get the values and use it for my condition of which field should I filter. I have 30 possible parameters that a user can use. I am trying to combine filters based on if-else condition. This is the only solution I can think of. If you have any solution for this. please help me. I am just new to Django.

This is my code.

```
class NumberInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.NumberFilter):
    pass

class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    manufacturer__in = NumberInFilter(field_name='manufacturer', lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ['category', 'product_partnumber']

class ProductsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializers
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Products.objects.all()
        freq = self.request.query_params.get('specs', None)
        inloss = self.request.query_params.get('inloss', None)

        if freq is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(specifications__specification_id__exact=18, specifications__value__exact=freq)

        if inloss is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(specifications__specification_id__exact=28, specifications__value__exact=inloss)
    
        return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False
        serializer = ProductsSerializers(data=request.data, many=many)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            product=serializer.data
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(product, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

my queryset are not combining. it just getting the last true on if statement.

This is my model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_partnumber = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_link = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    pdf_link = models.URLField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'

class ProductSpecification(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='specifications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    specification = models.ForeignKey(Specification, related_name='specification_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Thank you so much

I am using filter backends to filter the products by `category` or by `manufacturer`, but I have a scenario where the user can also filter by `specification`. I have 34 total `specification` for example
frequency min, frequency max, voltage min, voltage max, insertion loss min, insertion loss max and etc.

it is dynamic, the user can use any of that for example the URL can be.

```
www.myurl.com/?freqmin=18&freqmax=56&voltmin=15
```

or the user can only provide the voltage like

```
www.myurl.com/?voltmin=15&voltmax=30
```

I am trying to create a dynamic filter where if freqmin is not none I will add a queryset, same on the other filter. I hope this helps. thank you.

Comment: can you add a URL example?

Comment: also, what are you exactly looking for? I thought at first that you manually want to filter data but I see that you are using `filter_backends ` and `filterset_class ` so you know that concept, are you trying to manually do it with some fields? please explain your target with example

Comment: @MahmoudAdel - I already added an example at the end of the post. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. Honestly, I only learn filter_backends on tutorials as part of my learning in using djangorestframework. I am really new to this.  Thanks.

Comment: sry for not getting back to you quickly, I hope that I will come up with a better solution very soon, but to put it right, you want to filter `ProductSpecification` and return `Products` that has that condition, right?

Comment: if so, does this help you to get your goal? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51471673/4984493

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Q objects from django.

from django.db.models import Q

```
class ProductsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializers
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Products.objects.all()
        freqmin = self.request.query_params.get('fmin', '')
        freqmax = self.request.query_params.get('fmax', '')
        vswrmax = self.request.query_params.get('vswr', '')
        connector1 = self.request.query_params.get('conn1', '')
        connector2 = self.request.query_params.get('conn2', '')
        ....

        if freqmin:
            criterion1 = Q(specifications__specification_id__exact=2, specifications__value__startswith=freqmin)
        else:
            criterion1 = Q()
        
        if freqmax:
            criterion2 = Q(specifications__specification_id__exact=2, specifications__value__endswith=freqmax)
        else:
            criterion2 = Q()
        
        if vswrmax:
            criterion3 = Q(specifications__specification_id__exact=8, specifications__value__exact=vswrmax)
        else:
            criterion3 = Q()
        
        if connector1:
            criterion4 = Q(specifications__specification_id__exact=9, specifications__value__exact=connector1)
        else:
            criterion4 = Q()

        if connector2:
            criterion5 = Q(specifications__specification_id__exact=10, specifications__value__exact=connector2)
        else:
            criterion5 = Q()
    
        if gain:
            criterion6 = Q(specifications__specification_id__exact=18, specifications__value__exact=gain)
        else:
            criterion6 = Q()

        ....


        queryset = Products.objects.filter(
            criterion1, criterion2, criterion3, criterion4,
            criterion5, criterion6
        )

        return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False
        serializer = ProductsSerializers(data=request.data, many=many)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            product=serializer.data
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(product, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This makes my ModelViewSet long but this works for me now. Please let me know if you have better approach. Thank you.